# How to detect a node is in a range when touch a button?

Tags: sprite-kit

Look at the image, The red rect is move from top to bottom. I want to know  when I touched the blue button, if the red rect is in the gray area. And when the rect is move over the greay area I want to know if the button is touched?

At first I tried determine the position of the red rect when I touched button, but if there are many rect, how to detect each one?

And also think if collision detection can do this, but I have no ideal.
So please help.Thanks.

[The example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvhkM.png)

Comment: We are gonna need more info about what you have tried so far, like the code you've written. You likely need to hold onto the rects you care about so when the button is pressed you know which rect is which and can respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that your red rect, the blue button and gray area are each a `SKNode` or childs of his, e.g: `SKSpriteNode` or a `SKShapenode`.

You can check the collision at any time in the update function.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
{
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    if red_rect.intersects(blue_button) && red_rect.intersects(gray_area)
    {
        // at this point the red_rect touched the blue_button
        // and the red_rect is over the gray_area

        // *your code here*
    }
}
```

You can find more information about the [intersect(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483140-intersects) function here.